# Leibniz rule in $H^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega$ be an open 1-regular subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given $ u,v \in H^1(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$, how can you prove that $uv \in H^1(\Omega) $ and $\partial_j(uv)=v\partial_j u +u\partial_j v$ almost everywhere for every $j=1,\dots,n$ ?

I already proved that $uv,u\partial_j v ,v\partial_j u\in L^2(\Omega) $ (and therefore $v\partial_j u +u\partial_j v \in L^2(\Omega)$) but I'm having trouble proving that

\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega (v\partial_j u +u\partial_j v) \varphi=-\int_\Omega uv \partial_j \varphi \ \ \ \ \forall \varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)
\end{equation}

We know that $C_0^\infty(\overline\Omega)$ is dense in $H^1(\Omega)$ so I took $\lbrace u_n \rbrace_{n\geq 1},\lbrace v_n\rbrace_{n\geq 1}\subset C_0^\infty(\overline\Omega)$ such that $\left|\left|u_n-u \right| \right|_{1,\Omega}\rightarrow 0$ and $\left|\left|v_n-v \right| \right|_{1,\Omega}\rightarrow 0$ but I'm stuck in proving that $\left| \left| v_n\partial_j u -v\partial_j u\right|\right|_{0,\Omega}\rightarrow 0$ and $\left| \left| u_n\partial_j u -u\partial_j v\right|\right|_{0,\Omega}\rightarrow 0$. If I'm I able to prove that then the result will come out easily.

Comment: You don't need to check norm convergence. You want to check things like e.g. $\int_\Omega u_n v_n \partial_j \phi \to \int_\Omega uv \partial_j \phi$ where $v \to v_n, \partial_j v_n \to \partial_j v$ in $L^2$ and similarly for $u$. Since $\phi, \partial_j \phi$ are bounded you have e.g. $v_n \partial_j \phi \to v \partial_j \phi$ in $L^2$. Then the convergence of the integrals is just joint continuity of the $L^2$ inner product.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I was trying to kill an ant with a heavy machine gun haha